# fixed responsive top bar is covering second fixed top bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i have a css problem and i can't get through it. I searched everywhere for answers and then finally came here, at stackoverflow. I am making a website that have two fixed navbars, one on top and one below the other. Both are responsive too. When i resize my window, the first navbar has padding so basically it's height gets bigger and cover the second navbar. Can you please suggest any method to overcome this? Here is my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
.secondnav {
background:red;
width:100%;
height:42px;
position:fixed;
top:47px;
left:0;
right:0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#help" class="active">Help</a>
  <a href="#terms">Terms</a>
  <a href="#privacy">Privacy</a>
  <a href="#cookies">Cookies</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="secondnav">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i resize the window, the first navbar height increases, and therefore covers the second navbar, how to fix this? and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put two navs inside another div with position fix. and remove position fix of two navs, here the code and css and html i did modify, hope this helps !

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.outer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  widtH: 100%;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
.secondnav {
background:red;
width:100%;
height:42px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#help" class="active">Help</a>
    <a href="#terms">Terms</a>
    <a href="#privacy">Privacy</a>
    <a href="#cookies">Cookies</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="secondnav">
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But When i resize the window and the navbar becomes responsive, i can't scroll the navbar because the div is fixed. how to solve this? thanks again!

Comment: @RidanAsif so you want the scrollbar scrolling when you scroll window ?

Just remove position: fixed of class outer

Comment: no i can't scroll the links when it becomes responsive. I'm not talking about the body

Comment: u gotta put more content beneath the navs and check again, now u only have navs, and nothing beneath how could u scroll

Comment: Yeah. I added more links. So i cannot scroll beneath.

Comment: I need to add more links. Please help